# Delete storyboard xcode 4.2 iOS 5?

Tags: ios5, storyboard, xcode4.2

I created a project in xcode 4.2 using the feature of storyboard. I have done most of the work but now i came to know that storyboards are not available in pre-iOS 5 devices. Is there any way to remove this storyboard from the project without creating a new project? I don't want to do all the work again... any suggestions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Delete the "Main Storyboard base name" in your Info.plist file and add a "Main nib" name (what was MainWindow in standard templates) or supply your app delegate class name to `UIApplicationMain()` in main.m

Comment: thanks for the reply.. do i need to create the views like tab bar etc which in were in the storyboard again in the MainWindow?

Comment: when you create a MainWindow.xib you need to set the file's owner class to UIApplication, add the application delegate (as an object and set the class, wire up to owner's delegate property). connect the window to the window property of the delegate. Then add a tab bar controller to the window and add the view controllers inside (you can specify a nib name for the view controllers in the identity inspector). wire up any other neccessary properties of your delegate / view controllers